# Python numpy not saving array ()

Tags: python-2.7, numpy, save

I am getting a strange error when trying to (binary) save some arrays in python 2
I have isolated the error, in particular supposing

```
p1 = [1, 5, 10, 20]
p2 = [1, 5, 10, 20, 30]    
p3 =np.zeros( (5,10), dtype=float)
```

then

```
np.save("foo1", (p1, p2))
np.save("foo2", (p1, p3))
```

works ok,but

```
np.save("foo3", (p2, p3))
```

returns an error
[image]

Any ideas what is happening? 
The error says "setting an array element with a sequence"
Tried looking around, converting the arrays and so on but to no avail.
What is funny is that as mentioned the first saves are ok, and p1 is very similar to p2...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The error is not due to `np.save`, but coming from trying to create an array from nested sequences. I get a similar but different  error, probably because I am working on the development version, using any of the variants of `np.array`:

```
>>> np.array((p2, p3))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (5,10) into shape (5)
```

Not sure if this qualifies as a bug, but what's tripping numpy is the fact that the first dimension of `p2` and `p3` is the same, 5 in your case. So numpy thinks it should create an array `arr` of shape `(2, 5, ...)`. It then assigns the values in `p2` to `arr[0, :]` with no problems. But when it tries to assign the values in `p3` to `arr[1, :]` is when the error happens: you are trying to stick into a single position, e.g. `arr[1, 0]`, the 5 elements in `p3[0, :]`.

Numpy could probably be smarter about this, and not assume that a matching dimension means that the depth of all sequences is the same, as it seems to be doing. You may want to ping the numpy mailing list to see if one of the devs has a more informed opinion on whether this is undesirable behavior, or a design choice.

Comment: Thanx for the answer. This can lead to a bug that only happens rarely... It might be worth adding an empty array when saving more than one arrays to be sure nothing goes wrong then,
e.g. np.save("foo4", ("data_for_foo",p2, p3))

Comment: Wow this has been happening to me and I only just found this fix. Thanks so much.